# How to update solrconfig.xml with Java code? (Solr Cloud)

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solrcloud, solrconfig

I want to edit solrconfig.xml to enable Solr SpellCheck.(Using solr cloud) I already do this via zookeper on the server, but I want to implement this in my Java code.

- I take a look at Solrj to edit config files but I couldn't find anything for this.
- I also take a look at Config API guide (https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/config-api.html#commands-for-handlers-and-components) but configAPI doesn't change anything on solrconfig.xml, it just writes changes on configoverlay.json and it doesn't help to me.

Is there any idea how to update/add solrconfig.xml on Solr Cloud with Java?
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to use ZooKeeper API to update file on ZooKeeper. This can be done with Java if you want to but a simple bash script could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to upload the configs.

```
public void uploadConfig(String confName, File confDir) throws IOException {
  SolrZkClient zkClient = new SolrZkClient(zkConnectString, 30000, 30000,
      new OnReconnect() {
        @Override
        public void command() {
        }
      });
  new ZkConfigManager(zkClient).uploadConfigDir(confDir.toPath(), confName);
  zkClient.close();
}
```